# MIDI file parser reaches end of file before all tracks have been read

Tags: vb.net, media-player, media, midi, audio-player

I am writing a MIDI file parser in VB.NET. The program works perfectly for single track/Format 0 MIDI files however errors occur when dealing with multiple tracks.
This is my code for reading tracks in:

```
For x As Integer = 0 To metadata.NumberTracks - 1
   dataString = ""
   While Not (dataString.EndsWith("MTrk"))
      dataString = dataString & Chr(reader.ReadByte)
   End While
 
   Dim trk As New Track
   Dim numberBytes As Integer = 0
   For z As Integer = 0 To 3
      numberBytes = (256 * numberBytes) + reader.ReadByte
   Next
   Dim runningStatusType As Byte
   Dim runningStatusChannel As Byte
   Do
      trk.addEvent(getNextEvent(reader, runningStatusType, runningStatusChannel))
   Loop Until GetType(EndOfTrack) = trk.getLastEvent().GetType
Next
```

The `getNextEvent` function determines whether the event is channel-voice or a meta-event and returns the correct event type, passing the BinaryReader object into the event's constructor by reference so that it can independently read its own event data.

The problem is that the BinaryReader reaches the end of the file and throws an EndOfStream exception before the above For loop has iterated over all the tracks

I have tried using the number of bytes in each track as a condition for the `Do` loop which adds the events, instead of reading until the EndOfTrack message is received, however this produces similar errors.

I stress again that this issue only occurs in multi-track MIDI files, and seeing as multi-track files are identical to single track files, except with additional tracks following the first, I would expect that my program would work.

Is there an element of MIDI files that I have not accounted for, such as tracks within tracks, causing the program issues or have I approached the problem from the wrong angle?

I am on my second re-write of this project and I have been working with MIDI files for about 2 years, and I still do not understand why multi-track files do not work

If anyone could help point the issue out I'd be more than grateful.
Many thanks,
Roy H

Answer (score 0):

If the code works with single-track files, then it correctly reads the "MTrk" identifier of the first track.
But the code shown does not read the four "MTrk" bytes that come before the length of each following track.

Comment: My apologies. The part of my code which reads the Track Header did not make it into my post. I have now added the loop which reads the header to the post above. I believe this should still work however the EndOfStream errors persist. Is there something wrong with the loop I have just added?

Answer (score -1):

As we can see in the line of code highlighted below:

```
trk.addEvent(getNextEvent(reader, runningStatusType, runningStatusChannel))
```

You have not identified the constructor class in the VB file which has not been allocated the same amount of memory as the function that appears later on.

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean by this. The event type is identified inside that `getNextEvent` function, and then the correct constructor is used to create the object that the function returns.